# Variable in souce's dataset-id

Tags: google-bigquery

Let's say Nov 10 data is
for USA: `project_123.123456.data_20201110`
for Canada: `project_123.123457.data_20201110`
for Brazil: `project_123.123458.data_20201110`

How would you create a query where you can change the dataset-id depending on the country?
E.g. something like this, but this doesn't work obviously

```
DECLARE USA, CAN, BRA INT64;
SET (USA, CAN, BRA) = (123456, 123457, 123458);

SELECT * 
FROM `project_123.x.data_20201110`
WHERE x = USA
```

I do not want to remember which number is for which country, just want to create some variables once and forget it. With _TABLE_SUFFIX we can change the table name, but here I want to change the dataset_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is one of the options you have

```
DECLARE USA, CAN, BRA INT64;
DECLARE x STRING;

SET (USA, CAN, BRA) = (123456, 123457, 123458);
SET x = 'USA';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''
SELECT * 
FROM `project-123.''' || 
  CASE x 
    WHEN 'USA' THEN USA
    WHEN 'CAN' THEN CAN
    WHEN 'BRA' THEN BRA
    ELSE USA
  END
  || '''.data_20201110`
'''
```

Another (less verbose) option -

```
DECLARE x, USA, CAN, BRA INT64;

SET (USA, CAN, BRA) = (123456, 123457, 123458);
SET x = USA;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''
SELECT * 
FROM `project-123.''' || x || '''.data_20201110`
'''
```

Comment: thank you. A follow-up question: in this case in the bottom right corner it says: 'WARNING: Could not compute bytes processed estimate for script.'. Is there any workaround for this? Would be super useful to know whether I do something silly and would get scan gigabytes of data by accident before doing it.

Comment: see [Debugging BigQuery Stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64990529/5221944) - it gives an idea :o)