# Debugging BigQuery Stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, google-bigquery

Is there any way I can use print statements within BigQuery stored procedure? I have a stored procedure like below, I like to see how SQL statement is generated to debug the issue or any other better way to debug what stored procedure is producing etc.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `myproject.TEST.check_duplicated_prc`(project_name STRING, data_set_name STRING, table_name STRING, date_id DATE)
BEGIN
  DECLARE sql STRING;
  set sql ='Select date,col1,col2,col3,count(1) from `'||project_name||'.'||data_set_name||'.'||table_name|| '` where date='||date_id ||' GROUP BY date,col1,col2,col3 HAVING COUNT(*)>1';
    --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (sql);
    print(sql)
END;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are number of approaches for debugging / troubleshooting stored proc

One of the simplest - to `see how SQL statement is generated` - slightly adjust your stored proc as in below example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `myproject.TEST.check_duplicated_prc`(project_name STRING, data_set_name STRING, table_name STRING, date_id DATE, OUT sql STRING)
BEGIN
  -- DECLARE sql STRING;
  set sql ='Select date,col1,col2,col3,count(1) from `'||project_name||'.'||data_set_name||'.'||table_name|| '` where date='||date_id ||' GROUP BY date,col1,col2,col3 HAVING COUNT(*)>1';
    --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (sql);
END;
```

Then, you can run below to see generated SQL

```
DECLARE sql STRING;
CALL `myproject.TEST.check_duplicated_prc`('project_name', 'data_set_name', 'table_name', '2020-11-24', sql);
SELECT sql;
```

with output

[image]

As you can see here - you are missing apostrophes here `where date=2020-11-24` so you can fix your stored proc

Comment: Thank you. This solve my current problem, however, is there any print statement in BigQuery stored procedure? In oracle PL/SQL dbms_output.put_line was very handy to track the flow of logic.

Comment: Happy it solves your current issue. Please consider also voting up the answer. Meantime, to mimic `print` you can just simply use `select` to output needed info. you can see more for [Debugging statements in Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/debugging-statements#assert) and [System variables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#system_variables)